# Firefox OS Simulator media storage

Tags: firefox, mozilla, simulator, firefox-os

I'm testing the Firefox Simulator recently, and I noticed that for the add-on simulator the Gallery reads the pictures from /pictures on my pc, and Video reads the videos from /videos as well.

Later I ran the simulator on my mac, it can get music from /itunes, pictures from /users/username/pictures but I don't know where to put the video files for the simulator to read. I have tried the fake-sdcard folder and /users/username/movies, they both didn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can put `.mp4` or `.3gp` videos in any point of the fake-sd folder
this should work